# How to open Images in Stflacon Library in recycler View?

Tags: android

Here is the library dependency:

```
implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:stfalcon-imageviewer:0.1.0'
```

Here is the adapter class of the Recycler View:

```
public class QuotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuotesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<QuotesModel> quotesModelList;
    Context context;

    public QuotesAdapter(List<QuotesModel> quotesModelList, Context context) {
        this.quotesModelList = quotesModelList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.quotes_layout,
                parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        QuotesModel quotesModel = quotesModelList.get(position);
        holder.cardView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.item_animation_fall_down));

        Picasso.get().load(quotesModel.getImages()).fit().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholders).into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.e("Size of Quotes is :",String.valueOf(quotesModelList.size()));
        return quotesModelList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cardView;
        ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.images);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I open these images in "imageView" with this library for full-screen images?

Comment: after selecting the image you want to open in full screen? please let me know if yes then you need to add select/click listner

Comment: yes @Damodhar, this is exactly what i need ?